# Speeding up simulation code & ideas to make it more efficient

Tags: python

I created a quick monte-carlo simulation which seems to do what I want (simple version below).

```
import numpy as np
import os
import scipy.stats as sp

sigma = 0.5
u = 10
mu = 100


no_sim = int(10e3)
no_col = 2
mat_res = np.zeros((no_sim,no_col)) #results matrix holder

lim = 40e3 # parameter 1 - needs to vary
xs = 2000 # parameter 2 - needs to vary


for i in range(1,no_sim):
    no_clm = sp.poisson.rvs(mu=mu,size=1)
    clm_sev = sp.lognorm.rvs(s=sigma,scale=np.exp(u),size=no_clm)
    
    temp_mat = np.zeros((np.size(clm_sev),2)) # temp matrix for calculations
    
    temp_mat[:,0] = clm_sev
    temp_mat[:,1] = np.minimum(lim,np.maximum(0,temp_mat[:,0]-xs)) #want to expand this step for various values of lim and xs, e.g. 5 different options
    
    
    mat_res[i,0] = np.sum(temp_mat[:,0])
    mat_res[i,1] = np.sum(temp_mat[:,1])
    
    

#want these mean values for various different lim and xs values which are predefined
print("mean 1 is %s" % np.mean(mat_res[:,0]),
      "mean 2 is %s" % np.mean(mat_res[:,1]))
```

I am trying to do two things:

1. Speed up the efficiency of the code, I will need to run over a million simulations in reality so want to do this in the best way possible - currently it takes a five minutes or so to run a million simulations
2. expand the code in an efficient way so that I can vary the parameters `lim` and `xs` and get a new result - i.e. right now I have `lim = 40e3` and `xs = 2000`

but I would also want to run it with say `lim = 50e3` and `xs = 1000` and then return back the mean value in the print (along with the original mean for the original `lim` and `xs` parameters). One solution is to wrap the for-loop into a function with the parameters I require, however as I only use the `lim` and `xs` parameters in one line in the monte carlo simulation I don't think it's efficient to run the whole simulation again from scratch, but I can't think of any good way to build it into the for-loop as it stands.

Comment: If you have working code and you're looking for improvements, you should post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I get missing variable errors for mu, sigma, and u. Can you edit your code to provide these variables?

Comment: Sorry - updated code. I will post there too, I wasn't sure what the best place was to post. @NickODell

Answer (score 1):

You can use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) library to paralelize your code. If you can work only with numpy's arrays and operations to process your data you can also use [numpy's vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html). As [Glauco said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70523682/14643807) you can also optimize your code.

I made a snippet that use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). This is **not at all** optimised, is just a draw for your reference, however in my computer exec time improved roughly 2.9x.

```py
import time
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial

import tqdm
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sp


def simulation_0(mu: int, sigma: int, scale: float = np.exp(1)):
    no_clm = sp.poisson.rvs(mu=mu, size=1)

    # Your scale was np.exp(u), I set it to be a parameter for example purposes.
    return sp.lognorm.rvs(s=sigma, scale=scale, size=no_clm)


def simulation_1(xs: int, lim: int, mu: int, sigma: int, scale: float = np.exp(1)):
    # want to expand this step for various values of lim and xs, e.g. 5 different options
    return np.minimum(lim, np.maximum(0, simulation_0(mu=mu, sigma=sigma, scale=scale) - xs))


def simulation(xs: int, lim: int, mu: int, sigma: int, scale: float = np.exp(1)):
    with open("inputs.csv", "a") as fwriter:
        fwriter.write(f"{xs}, {lim}\n")

    sim_0_res = simulation_0(mu=mu, sigma=sigma, scale=scale)
    with open("simulation_0.csv", "a") as fwriter:
        fwriter.write(f"{sim_0_res},")

    sim_1_res = simulation_1(xs=xs, lim=lim, mu=mu, sigma=sigma, scale=scale)
    with open("simulation_1.csv", "a") as fwriter:
        fwriter.write(f"{sim_1_res},")


def simulation_wrapper(xs_lim_tuple: tuple, mu: int, sigma: int, scale: float = np.exp(1)):
    return simulation(xs=xs_lim_tuple[0], lim=xs_lim_tuple[1], mu=mu, sigma=sigma, scale=scale)


def main():
    # Constants
    mu = 0.5
    sigma = 0.5

    # The parameters to sweep
    lim = np.linspace(30e3, 50e3, 100)  # parameter 1 - needs to vary
    xs = np.linspace(1000, 3000, 100)  # parameter 2 - needs to vary
    # Creates a matrix with all the combinations
    sweep_parameters = np.array(np.meshgrid(xs, lim)).T.reshape((np.size(lim) * np.size(xs), 2))

    # Create a pool with N threads (N is set to be the number of threads)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())

    # This allows us to "initialize" the function call, since the mu and sigma will not change throughout the
    # execution we can already set these parameters.
    partial_function = partial(simulation_wrapper, mu=mu, sigma=sigma)

    # TQDM is only used to display a progressbar
    for _ in tqdm.tqdm(pool.imap(partial_function, sweep_parameters), total=np.shape(sweep_parameters)[0]):
        pass


def main_no_parallel():
    # Constants
    mu = 0.5
    sigma = 0.5

    # The parameters to sweep
    lim = np.linspace(30e3, 50e3, 100)  # parameter 1 - needs to vary
    xs = np.linspace(1000, 3000, 100)  # parameter 2 - needs to vary
    # Creates a matrix with all the combinations
    sweep_parameters = np.array(np.meshgrid(xs, lim)).T.reshape((np.size(lim) * np.size(xs), 2))

    # This allows us to "initialize" the function call, since the mu and sigma will not change throughout the execution we
    # can already set these parameters.
    partial_function = partial(simulation_wrapper, mu=mu, sigma=sigma)

    # TQDM is only used to display a progressbar
    for sweep_parameter in tqdm.tqdm(sweep_parameters, total=np.shape(sweep_parameters)[0]):
        partial_function(sweep_parameter)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    exec_times = []
    for i in range(5):
        start_time = time.time()
        main()
        exec_times.append(time.time() - start_time)
        print(f"--- {exec_times[-1]} seconds ---")
    print(f"\nParallelization Avg Exec Time: {np.average(exec_times)}\n")

    exec_times = []
    for i in range(5):
        start_time = time.time()
        main_no_parallel()
        exec_times.append(time.time() - start_time)
        print(f"--- {exec_times[-1]} seconds ---")
    print(f"\nNo-Parallelization Avg Exec Time: {np.average(exec_times)}\n")
```

Output:

```sh
100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:01<00:00, 6492.83it/s]
--- 1.5754084587097168 seconds ---
100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:01<00:00, 6395.57it/s]
--- 1.585716724395752 seconds ---
100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:01<00:00, 6657.03it/s]
--- 1.5238027572631836 seconds ---
100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:01<00:00, 6705.56it/s]
--- 1.5113093852996826 seconds ---
100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:01<00:00, 6691.30it/s]
--- 1.5149972438812256 seconds ---

Parallelization Avg Exec Time: 1.5422469139099122

100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:04<00:00, 2216.83it/s]
--- 4.511844873428345 seconds ---
100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:04<00:00, 2202.73it/s]
--- 4.540390491485596 seconds ---
100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:04<00:00, 2247.02it/s]
--- 4.450916051864624 seconds ---
100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:04<00:00, 2237.04it/s]
--- 4.470769166946411 seconds ---
100%|██████████| 10000/10000 [00:04<00:00, 2215.68it/s]
--- 4.513864517211914 seconds ---

No-Parallelization Avg Exec Time: 4.497557020187378
```

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately montecarlo is a trivial problem to parallelize, but i suggest to you to proceed in 2 steps:

1. optimization
   You can do benchmark in order to find wich statements are the slowest and try to refactor in an efficient way:
   there are some profilers to do these kind of stuff
   (i also wrote [perf tool](https://github.com/glaucouri/perf_tool) for a similar problem)
2. parallelize computation
   Using library like [ray](https://www.ray.io/) [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html) or [celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html)
   you will find a lot of benefits in performance, you should split your computation problem in order to create a bunch of tasks, for example if you works on a single machine with 8CPU, you can reduce the montecarlo in a sum of 8 small montecarlo.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can get a 20x speedup by using vectorization and doing more of the operations in numpy.

I did need to make some slight changes to the simulation itself, though. Specifically, instead of sampling no_clm every time through the loop, I sample it once per "batch," and use the same value for the entire batch.

Once I make this simplification, it's possible to create a matrix of log-norm sampled values, and apply the clipping and summation to each row of that matrix. This means that more of the calculation happens in numpy.

Here's the code:

```
def sim(xs, lim, no_sim):
    mat_res = np.zeros((no_sim,no_col)) #results matrix holder
    batch_size = 100
    for i in range(0, no_sim, batch_size):
        if i + batch_size >= no_sim:
            batch_size = no_sim - i
        no_clm = sp.poisson.rvs(mu=mu,size=1)[0]
        clm_sev = sp.lognorm.rvs(s=sigma,scale=np.exp(u),size=(batch_size, no_clm))

        mat_res[i:i+batch_size,0] = np.sum(clm_sev, axis=1)
        mat_res[i:i+batch_size,1] = np.sum(np.clip(clm_sev - xs, 0, lim), axis=1)
    return mat_res
```

Benchmark results:

| Method | Timing |
| --- | --- |
| No vectorization | 1.380s per 10k loops |
| Batch size 10 | 0.176s per 10k loops |
| Batch size 100 | 0.051s per 10k loops |
| Batch size 1000 | 0.036s per 10k loops |

Increasing batch size will have the benefit of increasing the speed, at the cost of re-using the same no_clm value multiple times. I think a sweet spot for this is around 100.

Because this method only uses one core, this speedup will stack with the parallelization suggestion that @pinxau1000 made.